# jquery form validation on checkbox

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, checkbox

I want an error message to show if the user has NOT checked an option on the checkboxes...I have tried the following code:

```
if (!$('input[name="problems[]"]').is(':checked')) {
                    var error = true;
                    $('#option_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#option_error').fadeOut(500);
                }
```

but regardless of whether it is checked or not it shows the error message?

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery validate plugin, or you just want to do this manually?

Comment: What is `$('#option_error').length` at the time of code execution? What is `$('input[name="probles[]"]').length` at the time of code execution? At what time is this code executed?

Comment: I'm trying to do it manually

Comment: it's executed when the form submit button is pressed

Comment: [this probably has the answer to your questions](http://jsfiddle.net/wsBmz/)

Comment: @John: [As you can see from this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrHmW/), there is no immediate problem with the code as such. Problems could be taht either your input or your error message is not being found. If you say it's executed on submit, another problem could be that you proceed to submit regardless of the value of `error`. We would need to see some more surrounding code.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy your jsfiddle gives the same error checked or not.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: `not` excludes a matching item from a set. Sure, you could validate that `problems[]` that are not checked yield a list with a length of `0`. It seems far more semantically correct to me to just check the inverse of `is`, as in the original question, as `is` yields a boolean. As your code is written, it will always yield the same output, for the same reason that Bhatt's answer did.

Comment: oddly deleting the first line and retyping it EXACTLY the same has made it start working? Thanks for all your tries..

Comment: @John as David said, you should show us where you're executing it, and  also your html might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function testing() {            
        if (document.getElementById('problems').checked == false) {               
            document.getElementById('option_error').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('option_error').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('option_error').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('option_error').fadeOut(500);

        }
    }
```